# suspicious large install file?

Tags: ktorrent

I was gonna install Ktorrent from the Terminal with the command

```
sudo apt install kbittorrent
```

and I was asked

```
After this operation, 354 MB of additional disk space will be used
```

but can this really be right? Little ol' Ktorrent is a 354 MB installation? That's double the size of heavy image tool GIMP!

Is it safe to install this?

Comment: What is the *full* output? Probably it needs to get a huge number of other packages (dependencies) as well.

Comment: I assume the command is `sudo install ktorrent`?  The ubuntu repositories do not have a package `kbittorrent`

Comment: ktorrent has an installed size of [4.5 Megabytes](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ktorrent), however it has a ton of dependencies. I get "After this operation, 319 MB of additional disk space will be used." (I assume the difference is that maybe I already have a few of the dependencies installed.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

KTorrent takes up about as much disk space as any other application does, but you're likely seeing a combination of all the packages that would have to be installed as a result. If you're not running KDE already this effectively means the amount of disk space needed for the core libraries (Qt) used.

Comment: ktorrent is 1Mb ;)

Comment: Yes, the total includes all the new dependent packages listed, though I cannot find anything in the apt docs that says this explicitly. It is implied, though, similarly to how replacing a package will report 0 bytes.